# Как удалить одинаковые буквы из строки? - Java SE

Tags: java

Возник вопрос: Как удалить одинаковые буквы из строки?
Есть вот это:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word[0].length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < word[0].length(); j++) {
        if(word[0].charAt(i) == word[0].charAt(j)) {
            word[0] = word[0].replace((word[0].charAt(i)), "");
            word[0] = word[0].replace((word[0].charAt(j)), "");
        }
    }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю проблема в этой строчке

```
word[0] = word[0].replace((word[0].charAt(i)), "");
```

Видимо я пытаюсь заменить char на string, поэтому и не работает. Пожалуйста, подскажите как мне реализовать эту функцию.

Пример работы, должно быть так: 
на входе - Java 
на выходе - Jv 
То есть должны удаляться все символы, встречающиеся более 1 раза

Comment: Это в корне меняет дело. Регистр учитывать? Неалфавитные символы в строке встречаться могут? Какой набор символов используется?

Comment: Нет, регистр не важен, да, символы встречаться могут. Набор символов: [a-z] [а-я] [0-9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "Java 8 RulezZz";

Map<Integer, Long> frequencies = str.toLowerCase()
                                    .codePoints()
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                      Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

String duplicates = frequencies.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
                      .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                      .map(Character::toChars)
                      .map(String::valueOf)
                      .filter(i -> !i.equals(" "))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?i)[" + duplicates + "]", ""));
```

Код в основном использует появившееся в Java 8 механизмы функционального программирования - Stream API, лямбды и ссылки на методы. Google поможет найти огромное количество вводных статей в эту область. Если хочется ознакомиться с вопросом подробнее, могу посоветовать учебник Уорбэртона "Лямбда-выражения в Java 8" или "Java SE 8 Базовый курс" Хорстманна. Попробую разобрать пример построчно:

`str.codePoints()` - вызов метода [codePoints()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) возвращает поток элементов типа `int`. Каждый элемент представляет код символа в оригинальной строке.

Вызов `boxed()` упаковывает каждый int в потоке в Integer.

Вызов `collect()` - терминальная операция преобразующая поток во что-либо. В данном случаем мы передаём параметром предопределённый коллектор `groupBy`, использующийся для группировки элементов.

Первым параметром коллектора мы передаём результат вызова статического метода `Function.identity()`, который возвращает лямбда-выражение, в свою очередь, возвращающее без изменений всё, что ему передадут. Можно было вместо `Function.identity()` написать `i -> i`.

Вторым параметром коллектора мы передаём результат вызова статического метода `Collectors.counting()`, который возвращает коллектор подсчитывающий количество элементов в потоке.

В результате манипуляций с этим потоком мы получаем в переменную `frequencies` 
отображение ([Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)), содержащий в ключах коды символов, а в значениях количество раз, который этот код встретился в потоке:

```
{32=2, 97=2, 82=1, 101=1, 117=1, 118=1, 56=1, 90=1, 122=2, 74=1, 108=1}
```

Вызов `frequencies.entrySet()` возвращает множество элементов отображения, которое мы тут же преобразуем в новый поток вызовом `stream()`.

В следующей строке - `filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)` мы отфильтровываем элементы значения которых равны единицы, то есть встретились в первом потоке только один раз.

Вызов `map(Map.Entry::getKey)` отбрасывает значения элементов, оставляя в потоке только ключи, так как значения нам больше не нужны, мы уже использовали их для фильтрации на предыдущем шаге.

Вызов `map(Character::toChars)` преобразует коды символов в сами символы.

Вызов `map(String::valueOf)` преобразует символы в строки.

Вызов `filter(i -> !i.equals(" "))` отфильтровывает пробелы. Мы же не хотим, чтобы в результате удаления дублирующихся пробелов в нашей итоговой строке все слова слиплись.

И, как и прошлый, этот поток заканчивается коллектором - `.collect(Collectors.joining())`, но на этот раз объединяющим отдельные строки потока в одну результирующую.

В результате манипуляций со вторым потоком мы получаем строку, содержащую все символы, которые встретились в оригинальной строке более одного раза, исключая пробелы.

Вызовом метода [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) мы разом удаляем из `str` все символы `duplicates`. Первым параметром метод получает регулярное выражение. Его первая часть - `(?i)` означает, что метод должен игнорировать регистр символов. Вторая часть, образующаяся в результате конкатенации - `[az]` представляет набор символов, которые надо заменить. Вторым параметром метода передаётся строка, на которую эти символы необходимо заменить. Так как нам надо их удалить, то заменяем мы их на пустую строку.

Или можно в императивном стиле:

```
Map<Character, Integer> chars = new HashMap<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
    if (c != ' ')
        chars.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);
}

sb.append("(?i)[");
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : chars.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() > 1)
        sb.append(entry.getKey());
}
sb.append("]");

System.out.println(str.replaceAll(sb.toString(), ""));
```

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает, но не могли бы вы немного прокомментировать код, просто я совсем недавно изучаю Java и мне многое здесь непонятно.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) А я пока комментарии к коду сочиню.

Comment: Извиняюсь за беспокойство, возник еще один вопрос, при вводе двух одинаковых букв разного регистра (Например в слове jAva) возникает ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 5
(?i)[] Подскажите как ее исправить пожалуйста

Comment: Не смог этого повторить. Но попробуйте дополненный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Character> chars = new HashSet();
for(int i = 0; i<string.length(); i++){
    chars.add(string.charAt(i));
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/NN8CsF)

Comment: Прошу прощения, не могли бы вы прокомментировать код, я не очень разбираюсь в нем

Comment: из строки берутся символы по одному и кладутся в коллекцию типа `Set`. Отличительной особенностью коллекции `Set` является то, что все элементы в ней уникальны